# admin.firestore is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried to resolve this issue, but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm testing the firebase **firestore** for the functions, but if I **serve** the functions this error always appears (if I deploy to the cloud, everything works just fine and without any problems)

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var serviceAccount = require("./xxxxxxxxxxx-firebase-adminsdk.json");

/*admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com"
});*/

var db = admin.firestore();
```

This works out just well, but when I do **firebase server --only functions**, this error appears

```
TypeError: admin.firestore is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\bachmann\cleverclass\cleverclass_functions\functions\index.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\konrad.bachmann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\konrad.bachmann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:32:3)
```

Maybe the serve functions doesn't recognize the firestore just yet? The cloud works just fine with this code, but live testing would speed up my process.

Comment: Check that you have the latest version of `firebase-admin` installed.

Comment: That actually worked out, thanks!